# Dynamic Linq to Entities...querying date fields

Tags: linq-to-entities

I am trying to use Linq to Entities with the Linq.Dynamic library (via Scott Guthrie) and I'm having some strange issues with querying dates.

```
var _date1 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30).Date;
var _date2 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(31).Date;
var dateField = "DUEDATE";

docs = db.DOCUMENT.Where("@0 >= @1", dateField, _date1).Where("@0 <= @1", dateField, _date2);
```

This return no results, when it definitely should... it's simply a between statement to grab records for the specified day, but LinqToEntities doesn't like the combo. Any ideas??

Comment: What is the generated SQL? L2E and Dynamic Query *do* work together, even with dates -- we do this all the time. Look at the SQL.

Comment: great idea...that helped me figure it out. Apparently I was just comparing a string to a string instead of a column to a date.

I just changed my linq query to:
.Where(dateField + " >= @0", _date1).Where(dateField + " <= @0", _date2);

and it's working great now. Thanks for the help.